# Compile Azure Functions (.csx files) on local machine

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using AzureQueue Trigger template and it would be great to write the functions in my local machine, compile and execute it and then deploy rather than writing it in the azure portal. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Krishh,

The answer is yes, but the experience is not great at the moment. Local development is an area we'll be investing more on as we enhance the service, but until we have a true first class local development experience, here's some documentation to get you started with what is currently available:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-run-local/

The Wiki on the host repository is another great source of information:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki

Keep an eye on the docs as we're iterating quickly and will be enhancing the documentation as the experience improves.

Comment: Local execution/unit testing with an easy setup would be a giant plus.

Answer (score 2):

This was published just today. Allows you to debug locally as per the article

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/

> - These tools are offered as a preview release and will have some rough spots and limitations
> - They currently only work with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with “Microsoft Web Developer Tools” installed
> - You must have [Azure 2.9.6 .NET SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518003&clcid=0x409) installed
> - Download and install [Visual Studio Tools for Azure Functions](https://aka.ms/azfunctiontools)