# Error in Azure Functions when running locally which has nuget package reference

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I tried the approach that was discussed over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733784/compile-azure-functions-csx-files-on-local-machine) to run Azure Functions on local machine. I was able to compile and run locally fine with the samples. But when I tried referencing nuget package by adding a project.json file and adding the namespace in my function it started throwing compilation error. On the portal it works fine. Am I missing any step?

project.json

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB": "1.6.3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

run.csx

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;

public static void Run(TimerInfo input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Verbose("C# Timer trigger function executed.");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krishh,

This should definitely work locally. You may need to check the following:

- Due to the way NuGet references are currently processed, please make sure you "touch" that file **while** the host is running. The host watches for file modifications and initiates a restore when it detects changes
- NuGet.exe (3.3.0 recommended) must either be in your path or you must have an environment variable named *AzureWebJobs_NuGetPath* set, with the path to nuget.exe

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue:  NuGet 3.5, VS2015 Update 3. Local build works fine for functions with no nuget package references...  I can add the same nuget package reference to a function app on azure and it works fine.  I've tried touching the project.json in the function directory as you mention here... where can I look for log output or where can I put a breakpoint to see what's going on/wrong?  (That compilation error output screen is really no help)  Many Thanks.